# Как сократить в шаблонах Django часто используемые блоки html

Tags: django, шаблоны

У меня в шаблоне нужно выводить много блоков (карды). Ну вот к примеру такой, упрощенно:

```
<div class="cover-card col-sm-6" style="background: url(/uploads/image.jpg) no-repeat center top;background-size:cover;">
<p>Text Caption</p>
</div>
```

Можно ли как-то обозначить эти блоки тегами, чтобы не писать каждый раз весь код блока?

Comment: Шаблоны Django. Наследование. https://habrahabr.ru/post/23132/

Answer (score 2):

смотри {% include %}  и собственные теги

https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/templates/builtins.html

https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/howto/custom-template-tags.html

---

Пример использования include

```html
{# base.html %}
...
{% for obj in obj_list %}
  {% include "sample.html" with object=obj %}
{% endfor %}
...

{# sample.html #}
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 cover-card" style="backgroud-image: url({{object.image.url}});">
  <p class="h4">{{ object.title }}</p>
  <p>{{object.description}}</p>
</div>
```

Кстати, для уменьшения html кода

> no-repeat center top;background-size:cover;

Вынеси в класс